# What can't I blow up with dynamite?

Tags: terraria

I know that Dynamite can destroy Hellstone *Bricks* but not Hellstone Ore, and that Dynamite can destroy meteorite, ebonstone, and the suit of "uninteresting" (Stone/Dirt/Mud/Grass) blocks.

Is Hellstone Ore the only dynamite proof blocks, or are there others as well? (Dungeon Bricks perhaps, or obsidian?)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As of 1.1.1, this is a complete list of all things immune to Dynamite (and Bombs, too):

- Dungeon Bricks of any color
- Any type of Chest (including Barrels and Trash Cans), even when empty
- Demon Altars
- Cobalt Ore
- Mythril Ore
- Adamantite Ore
- Hellstone, but *only* before the Wall of Flesh is defeated

Additionally, unsafe background walls (such as natural Dirt or generated Dungeon Brick Walls) are immune, unless the explosion reaches the edge of (or a hole in) the wall.

Comment: You might want to add the [Lihzahrd bricks](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Lihzahrd_Brick).